# PL/SQL String transformation: Alter string automated

Tags: string, plsql, transform, varchar, sql-function

is it possible in PL/SQL to transform string?
In my case i have VARCHARs like "COR_DIM_table1" and i qould like to get "COR_DIM_TAB_table1".
Is there a away to automate such things like:

1. Get position after "cor_dim_"
2. Insert "tab_"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of functions you can use.

REPLACE will replace a string, INSTR (and several variants of it) can find the search string and you can do SUBSTR to break apart the string, the append the parts

```
select REPLACE('COR_DIM_table1','table1','tab_table1') from dual;

REPLACE('COR_DIM_TABLE1','TABL
---------------------------------

COR_DIM_tab_table1
```

SUBSTR( string, start_position, [ length ] )

INSTR( string, substring [, start_position [,  nth_appearance ] ] )

```
select substr('COR_DIM_table1',1,length('COR_DIM_')) || 'tab' || substr('CO
R_DIM_table1',length('COR_DIM_')) from dual;

SUBSTR('COR_DIM_TABLE1',1,LENG
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

COR_DIM_tab_table1
```

There are also corresponding REGEX_REPL, REGEX_INSTR and REGEX_SUBSTR if your naming conventions are more complex.